# how to use setAllChecked(boolean) method of CheckBoxTableViewer class of jFace?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, jface, rcp

```
protected Control createDialogArea( Composite parent )
{
    Composite composite = new Composite( parent, SWT.NONE );
    composite.setLayoutData( new GridData( GridData.FILL_BOTH ) );
    composite.setLayout( new GridLayout( 2, false ) );
    Group consumedCmp = new Group( composite, SWT.BORDER );
    consumedCmp.setLayout( new GridLayout( 1, false ) );
    consumedCmp.setLayoutData( new GridData( SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true, 1, 1 ) );
    consumedCmp.setText( reg.getString("ASSIGN_AS_TXT") );
    btnMsConsumed = new Button( consumedCmp, SWT.RADIO );
    btnMsConsumed.setLayoutData( new GridData( SWT.FILL, SWT.CENTER, false, false, 1, 1 ) );
    btnMsConsumed.setText( ME_CONSUMED );
    btnRequired = new Button( consumedCmp, SWT.RADIO );
    btnRequired.setLayoutData( new GridData( SWT.FILL, SWT.CENTER, false, false, 1, 1 ) );
    btnRequired.setText( REQUIRED );
    Group tableCmp = new Group( composite, SWT.BORDER );
    tableCmp.setLayout( new GridLayout( 1, false ) );
    tableCmp.setLayoutData( new GridData( SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true, 1, 1 ) );
    tableCmp.setText( PART_ASSIGNMENT_INDICATOR );
    tableViewer = CheckboxTableViewer.newCheckList( tableCmp, SWT.CHECK | SWT.BORDER | SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.H_SCROLL );
    table = tableViewer.getTable();
    table.setLinesVisible( true );
    table.setLayoutData( new GridData( SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true, 1, 1 ) );
    Composite buttonCmp = new Composite( tableCmp, SWT.NONE );
    buttonCmp.setLayout( new GridLayout( 2, false ) );
    buttonCmp.setLayoutData( new GridData( SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, false, false, 1, 1 ) );
    btnSelectAll = new Button( buttonCmp, SWT.NONE );
    btnSelectAll.setLayoutData( new GridData( SWT.RIGHT, SWT.CENTER, true, false, 1, 1 ) );
    btnSelectAll.setText( reg.getString("SELECT_ALL_TXT") );
    btnSelectAll.addListener( SWT.Selection, new Listener()
    {
        @Override
        public void handleEvent( Event event )
        {
            //tableViewer.setAllChecked( true );
            for(TableItem item : table.getItems())
                item.setChecked(true);
        }
    });
    Button btnDeselectAll = new Button( buttonCmp, SWT.NONE );
    btnDeselectAll.setLayoutData( new GridData( SWT.LEFT, SWT.CENTER, true, false, 1, 1 ) );
    btnDeselectAll.setText( reg.getString("DESELECT_ALL_TXT") );
    btnDeselectAll.addListener( SWT.Selection, new Listener()
    {
        @Override
        public void handleEvent( Event event )
        {
            //tableViewer.setAllChecked( false );
            for(TableItem item : table.getItems())
                item.setChecked(false);
        }
    });
    initTable();
    return composite;
}

private void initTable()
{
    Iterator iter = ind.iterator();
    while( iter.hasNext() )
    {
        TableItem item = new TableItem( table, SWT.NONE );
        // this code works
        item.setText( ( String ) iter.next() );
        item.setChecked(true);
    }
    // the below code doesnot works
    //tableViewer.setAllChecked( true );
}
```

Can anyone give examples of the above case? At the start, all the items of the table should be checked.

I have some 5 items in table. By default, all the items should be checked. I will have 2 buttons select all , deselect all which should select all the items and deselect all the items respectively.

Can anyone give example for this?

Comment: Sorry, but it is not clear what your problem is here. What issue do you have with calling `setAllChecked`? We aren't going to write all your code for you, show us what you have tried.

Comment: Hi greg, since code was long I havent pasted it... Now I editied the question with code. Please check. Here in the code setAllChecked(true) is not working.. But it works if i check each items in the table..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use a JFace `CheckboxTableViewer` (or any other JFace viewer) you **must** use the JFace content provider together with a label provider and the `setInput` call.

You must **not** create `TableItem`s like you are doing - the JFace code won't know about the items and your code will misbehave. When you use JFace viewers you **never** manipulate the underlying table or tree items.

You appear to have a list `ind` which could be used as the input for the viewer so you would do something like:

```
tableViewer.setContentProvider(ArrayContentProvider.getInstance());

tableViewer.setLabelProvider(new LabelProvider());

tableViewer.setInput(ind);
```

(and remove all your code creating `TableItem`s)

`ArrayContentProvider` can deal with input which is an array or which implements the `List` interface.

With the table set up correctly using the providers the `setAllChecked` method will work.

Comment: But it was working in the previous version of our application. If you don't mind, can you give any documentation confirming that have to use contentproviders. Because I need to prove it if I wanna change the existing code logic.

Comment: I doubt you will find documentation that explicitly says don't use table items, but all tutorials on JFace will use content providers - they are the whole point of using the JFace viewers. Any study of the JFace code will show that it expects to be in complete control of the table contents. If it worked for you in the past you have been lucky, but it is still wrong.

Comment: I will go with your suggestion, since it wil simplify the code. Thanks for your suggestions greg!!